# delete record from parent table Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entity 
entityA.php and entityB.php

entityA.php

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mytable")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *          "foo"                        = "ACME\myBundle\Entity\entityB",
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ACME\myBundle\Entity\entityARepository")
 */
class entityA
{
..more code
```

entityB.php

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mytable_b")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ACME\myBundle\Entity\entityBRepository")
 */
class entityB extends entityA
{
```

I want delete object form entityB and (without query) delete also entityA

If I delete form entityA "automatically" delete form entityB but no viceversa

Comment: can i use something like postRemove ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `postRemove` entity listener set to your enetityB to delete parent entity.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-class